# monitoring tomcat requests per second?

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

How can I monitor current requests per second in Tomcat, using collectd. I was thinking about monitoring `access.log` and calculating requests with a script and then converting it to collectd but maybe there is an easier way to do it? Or maybe there is an easier way to do it using jmx? I was only able to find total requests and requests per thread.

Answer (score 7):

The JMX property you are looking for is called:

```
Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=ajp-apr-/10.0.0.1-9001,requestCount
```

(That's in the syntax used by Zabbix 1.9.x for its JMX collection. You may need to translate that for your own use, and adjust for your own connector, IP and port) Naturally you'll want to track the change in that value per second to get your graph.